# Is it possible to refer to this property value to use as another property name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, this

To refer to this.property, there is a getter:

```
var foo = {
  a: 5,
  b: 6,
  get c() {
    return this.a + this.b;
  }
}

console.log(foo.c) // 11
```

however, is it possible to do this during object initialization:

```
var foo = {
  HIDING: 0,
  get state() {
    return this.HIDING;
  }
  [this.HIDING]: { x: 0, y: 0 },
}
```

I expect

```
foo: {
  HIDING: 0,
  state: 0,
  0: { x: 0, y: 0 }
}
```

[Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers) this doesn't answer my question because it doesn't talk about using another property value as property name

Comment: `this.HIDING` is undefined before the object is initialized

Comment: oof, why does the canonical dupe target not cover this case properly... anyways, no, you cannot self-reference in an object initializer. The object is only accessible, after the initializer finished.

Comment: @ASDFGerte edit the answer? Or maybe add an answer?

Comment: If you want "hidden" properties, you can use private class properties in a class declaration, or else create your own Symbol instances for property identifiers.

Comment: "*Self-references in object literals / initializers this doesn't answer my question because it doesn't talk about using another property value as property name*" - see [t.j. crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10766107/1048572) which explains *why* it's not possible to refer to a property value before the object is created - regardless from where you try to reference it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616273/5131640 - this is the original answer that made this question duplicate

Comment: this is not a duplicate: they are asking about having a getter with a name that depends on another property: when `state` is `0`, they expect `foo.0` to be `{ x: 0, y: 0 }`, when `state` is `1`, they expect `foo.1` to be `{ x: 0, y: 0 }` etc. Am I right? However, I don't think it's possible because effectively this requires a getter of *any* property (since `state` may be anothing) and moreover it probably would be ill-defined (when `state` is `{a:1}`, what getter should be there?) However, this can easily be implemented as a method (`0` or `1` should be an argument) instead of a getter.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do it after initialization:

```
var foo = {HIDING: 0};
foo[foo.HIDING] = {x: 0, y: 0};
```